# Debug remotely Azure WebJob

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

I am currently working on the development of a WebJob which does a massive treatment (may take several hours). The WebJob depends on two web services & is a C# console app.

If I test it locally on my machine using  database and services that are on Azure, it works very well. But if I test it on Azure, I have lots of problems. I followed all the steps that are explained on the web to debug my WebJob, but when attaching the process to my website, I never see my WebJob processes.

Are there any steps needed to specifically debug an Azure Webjob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to debug my WebJob remotely by doing three things. The first was to remove SSL certificates attached to my WebSite. Second, when I attached the process to my WebJob, it had to be done at before it was running. Finally I updated the process list until the WebJob’s name appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the steps outlined here http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/WebJobs-GA-Series-Episode-1-WebJobs-Tooling-with-Brady-Gaster
Is your WebJob running Continuously or on a schedule?